# Arraylist within class stored in an Arraylist does not become serialized

Tags: java, serialization

I have an arraylist stored and in a myclass there is an arraylist and this arraylist with strings is empty and i cant understand why.

Since all the serialize of the outer arraylist works well and i can retrive all the information exept the strings within the arraylist i thought that the serialize function was not a problem but apprently it is. I cant see what i am missing and i spent all day trying to find the issue but i cant.

Anyone has an idea as to what i am doing wrong? no attributes are set to be transient so i dont understand why as it dosent get stored.

Peice of the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class Accounts implements Cloneable,Serializable
{

public Accounts()
{
}

//Attributes declared  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public ArrayList<String> lsttransact = new ArrayList<String>();  //  <-- This array is empty after load from serialied file
```

This class is stored in an arraylist and thats the one i serialize and in doing so this marked arraylist becomes empty. :(

//Regards

Comment: if you post your code maybe somebody could help

Comment: I would guess that it is because all of the arraylists inside the outer one are just references. If you don't post code though that is all that I can guess.

Comment: The actual Accounts child class could do the serialisation wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really simple as in the guard before using these values stored in this array was that "==" were used instead of opening the box and looking inside since the reference changed. The use of .equals() sorted this problem in a jiffy.

I just have to learn to chase the white rabbit thrue the code no matter how many miles of code there is! chucks it down to inexperience...but that will come with time!